# Objective-c: Is it possible to popup a UIScrollView when I hold a key for a few second

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to embed a UIScrollView in my app and set it default hidden. When I hold a key, i.e. `D` in the keyboard for 3 second, then this UIScrollView will popup, is it possible to implement this ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Why the closing and down votes? I think this is a very valid question, which mostly boils down to: how to detect that a key was pressed and held down for a certain amount of time?

Comment: Do you mean the onscreen keyboard or a bluetooth keyboard? That's a major difference.

Comment: can i know why u r hiding and showing the scrollview we can use set content

Answer (score 2):

If you weren't looking to long keyboard presses you'd look into using [UILongPressGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UILongPressGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

However, you are looking for long keyboard presses. Unfortunately I can't see this being possible with Apple' keyboards as long presses on keyboard keys are used for other things by Apple already. e.g. to provide accented versions of characters or other currency denominations. (try long pressing S or $)

Therefore I think you'd have to code your own keyboard entirely in order to do what you are hoping to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(showResetMenu:)];
[piece addGestureRecognizer:longPressGesture];
[longPressGesture release];


- (void)showResetMenu:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
    UIMenuController *menuController = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
    UIMenuItem *resetMenuItem = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Reset" action:@selector(resetPiece:)];
    CGPoint location = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:[gestureRecognizer view]];

    [self becomeFirstResponder];
    [menuController setMenuItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:resetMenuItem]];
    [menuController setTargetRect:CGRectMake(location.x, location.y, 0, 0) inView:[gestureRecognizer view]];
    [menuController setMenuVisible:YES animated:YES];

    pieceForReset = [gestureRecognizer view];

    [resetMenuItem release];
}
}
```

this is for simple button after long press on that you will get reset popup